# Change posts archive ordering

Tags: wp-query, order

I need to change the order of my default posts archives so I have added this to my functions.php but it doesn't affect anything... I've looked at various examples and from what I can see it should work.  Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? I commented out the archive check in case that helped, but nothing. Thanks :)

`function pre_get_posts_hook($query) {`

`//  if (  $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_archive() ) {
    if (  $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'post_featured' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC' ) );
      }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'pre_get_posts_hook' );`

Answer (score -1):

Scrap this figured it out!  A plugin was overriding these settings on the specific archive I need it on!  So probably without the plugin, the above would work :)